# Blocking light on a tiled level

Tags: java

I'm making a tiled(tiles size is 16px) level scrolling game in Java.
Right now I'm dealing with the lighting system.
I calculated the light gradient(as shown on the picture) with this code for each light(yellow blocks and tiles):

```
visMap = new int[level.getWidth() * level.getHeight()];

    int lighted = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < level.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < level.getHeight(); y++) {
            double xd = (this.x >> 4) - x;
            double yd = (this.y >> 4) - y;

            double distance = Math.sqrt(xd * xd + yd * yd);

            double p = power * 1.0;
            double bright = p - distance;

            visMap[x + y * level.getWidth()] = (int) (bright * power);
        }
    }
```

And now I'm trying to make the block somehow block the light(like in real life).
Is there a good method for this?
Thank's in advance,
Zaplik

The Picture: [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUTcF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Spread light recursively. Decrease with each level of recursion the light intensity with the appropriated amount. Keep also track of the direction light is moving. Once you hit an obstacle, stop that branch of the recursion.